# C++ - Replace base class method

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to call a base class method that, if it's overridden, call the overridden method, otherwise, call base class method.

The idea would be:
I have a base class virtual method that, if some runtime condition is met, then I instantiate a derived class method which completly replaces base class method. Now every time the base class method gets called, the derived method gets called instead.

I think this can be done modifying the virtual method table of the base class and replacing the method address in that table to the "overridden" new function's address.

I don't know if this is possible to archive using only inheritance. If not, which would be the best approach to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Don't mess with the vtable. Your code loses portability. Even a minor upgrade to the same compiler could change the rules out from beneath you and result in mystery bugs galore.

Comment: @user4581301 you might not even be *able* to mess with the vtable, there's no reason it couldn't be in read-only memory.  And if you do mess with it, it's shared between all the objects of that class so you'll affect them all - probably not what was intended.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is how non-pure virtual functions work.

> I wanto to call the method from base class instance.

Example:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "base"; };
};

struct Overrides : Base {
    void foo() override { std::cout << "overridden"; };
};

int main() {
    if (runtime_condition) {
        Overrides o;
        Base& b = o;
        b.foo(); // calls overridden
    } else {
        Base b;
        b.foo(); // calls base
    }
};
```

Comment: I want to call the method from base class instance. Not from derived class.

Comment: @FranciscoLinan I adjusted the example to call the function through a base reference. Is that what you mean?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: A better (ie more real-world practical) example might be something like: `Base *b; if (runtime_condition) { b = new Overrides; } else { b = new Base; } ... b->foo(); /* calls Base::foo() or Overrides::foo() accordingly... */ ... delete b; /* don't forget to make ~Base() virtual ...`